# PrestaShop ClassNotFoundException in FormExtension

Tags: symfony, composer-php, prestashop

So I just cloned a fully working Prestashop website to another server for testing purposes.

At first, only the Backoffice was working but the front-end of the website was not accessible.

After a few changes on the backoffice I was able to run the front-end, but everytime I make a small change on the backoffice dashboard, I run into this error and have to delete all the files and reconfigure everything again.

Can somebody help me please? Been looking at this problem for 2 days and no luck at all!

Can see the Error print

[image]

Comment: how did you clone it ? Is it a fresh install from a git repo, or did you copy/paste the folder ? Can you provide the code for the FormExtension file ?

Comment: @BernardPagoaga I copied all the files and the database. I haven't touched the FormExtension file or any file for that matter. Here is a link to the code https://pastebin.com/SB5Gb6Ra

Comment: Looks like an autoload issue. Did you copy the vendor directory too ? This is where it handles the autoload.

Comment: @matks Yes, I copied everything from the ftp. I ended up solving the problem by downloading a fresh prestashop project and copying the vendor folder to my clone!